# Implementing Birds Eye map mode in WP8 Nokia Maps

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

Is there any Birds eye map mode is available in, Windows phone 8 Nokia map. In the MapCartographicMode i only fond the following enum values.

```
 public enum MapCartographicMode
 {
    Road,
    Aerial,
    Hybrid,
    Terrain,
 }
```

Then how we implement Birds eye view in windows phone 8. Is there any other option available to set this mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "birds eye"? Is that not the same as Aerial or Terrain?

Comment: There is a mode known as birds eye. I don't know more about the view but there is one. I am also confused ie why i am asking.. :)

Comment: Do you mean the Birds Eye mode like on Bing Maps? Where have you seen this in WP8?

Comment: Yea. Exactly.. I am luking for a similar functionality

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `MapCartographicMode` for the map style that you want, and then set the `Pitch` property to a value between 0 and 180.

0 is the default value, which gives the flat map view. If you use a value around 60, this gives you a view that is more like the driving mode found in SatNav apps. Just tweak it to give the effect that you want.

If you want something more akin to the Bing "Birds Eye" view, then you will need to adjust the pitch based on the `ZoomLevel` (there is a [ZoomLevelChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.zoomlevelchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or you could bind it to a view model property).